# Implicit and Explicit Regex creation yield different exec results

Tags: javascript, regex, v8

I am searching on a largeish (500kb) document with a regex.  I am using node.js (v0.10.13), but the behaviour is the same in Chrome (31) DevTools.  With implicit regex creation I get what I expect to:

```
>/worker(?:.|\n)+Name:\s+(.+?)\s+Job title/.exec(text)
["worker   John Doe
                                                                 (s):
Name:                         Mrs Jean Smith          Job title", "Mrs Jean Smith"]
```

If I explicitly create a RegExp (which I need to do, since the expression can change at run-time) then it fails:

```
>new RegExp('worker(?:.|\n)+Name:\s+(.+?)\s+Job title').exec(text)
null
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create RegEx's with [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), you need to escape the special characters with double backslashes, like this

```
new RegExp('worker(?:.|\\n)+Name:\\s+(.+?)\\s+Job title').exec(text)
```